# Why my application somethings can't start?

Tags: android

My application only load data for ListView (Not contain image) .
Somethings my application can't start.
I watch logcat, it show message:

```
01-11 14:58:52.598: E/JavaBinder(265): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

I  go to Settings -> App -> Select my app and click Force stop. It will run ok.
Why? How fix this problem? thanks.

My code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        handler2 = new Handler();

        dtTitle = new profileAdapter(this, R.layout.layoutrowtitle);
        ListView lvTruyen = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTruyen);
        lvTruyen.setAdapter(dtTitle);
        lvTruyen.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DTO_Truyen dt = dtTitle.getItem(arg2);
                Intent myinten = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        TruyenDetail.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("Id", dt.ID);
                myinten.putExtras(b);
                startActivityForResult(myinten, 0);
            }
        });

        showProccess();
        startThread();

    }


public class profileAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DTO_Truyen> {

        public profileAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            View v = convertView;
            ViewWraperDV mwp;

            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater l = getLayoutInflater();
                v = l.inflate(R.layout.layoutrowtitle, null);
                mwp = new ViewWraperDV(v);
                v.setTag(mwp);
            } else {

                mwp = (ViewWraperDV) convertView.getTag();
            }

            TextView txtID = mwp.getLable();
            TextView txtTitle = mwp.getTitle();

            DTO_Truyen dt = this.getItem(position);
            txtID.setText(dt.ID + ": ");
            txtTitle.setText(dt.Title);

            return v;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code and any other logs so we can see what might be happening.

Comment: my code had upload. It run ok. but somethings it can't start.

Comment: post your profileAdapter class... is profileAdapter extending ArrayAdapter?

Comment: You need to make `ListView lvTruyen` a member variable of your activity, not a local variable of the method.

Comment: @user1497597 where is the data that is used to populate listview?

Comment: where is your ViewWraperDV  class

Comment: i load in function  startThread(); by Thread

Comment: you have to pass the arraylist through ur adapter constructure..

Comment: @user1497597 show that thread code .

Comment: My code run ok.But something can't start. it only display white screen.  I go to Settings -> App -> Select my app and click Force stop. It will run ok. i think , it is problem of memory.

Comment: @user1497597 if it memory issue it should be outofmemory error.

Comment: probably the cause is NullPointerException at `DTO_Truyen dt = this.getItem(position);`, here getItem() is returning `null` as ArrayAdapter is not populated with data...

Comment: @ Gopal Rao: why? if i click Force stop. It will run ok

Answer (score 0):

By the way your code doesn't have memory issue as Raghunandan says if it memory issue it should be outofmemory error and also not have any VM problem .

You have to understand that here you are using an adapter class which is responsible to fill the custom data for your ListView.

Every adapter class should get data(for e.g ArrayList) from its appropreate activity throuugh its constructor with the current context.
Like:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context, arraylist_data);
```

And this adapter object used as the adapter of the listview or gridview and use the setAdapter() to put.

And in your MyAdapter class you should be define your constructure with the appropreate parameters.Like:
    public class MyAdapter  extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList mData;

```
 public MyAdapter (Context mContext, ArrayList<DTO_Truyen> mData){
 this.mContext = mContext;
 this.mData = mData;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      //do any thing here... 
   }
}
```

Where your getView() method get all data through current position and put inside the custom layout ass well as any reaction.

Basically this is the way to put custom layout and data inside ListView. And about the exceptions, Raghunandan and Gopal Rao already explained. So just change your way of writing code and it will be fine.